# Is Sviatoslav Richter using the pedal in his recordings of Bach's "The Well-Tempered Clavier"?

Tags: piano, technique, johann-sebastian-bach

Is [Sviatoslav Richter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sviatoslav_Richter) using the pedal in his [recordings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPPphQT6Gws) of [*The Well-Tempered Clavier*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Well-Tempered_Clavier)?

I'm not able to listen and deduce whether he is using it or not.
(Since I like his way of playing, I would like to do the same - use the sustain pedal if he does, and not use it if he does not.)

Comment: I'm not able to view the link you posted, but based on other YouTube videos, I'd say "I can't tell." It does sound like he might be using some very, very light pedal, but it's hard to distinguish that from the natural reverb of the room he's recording it. FWIW, I found this comment ("The Russian pianists tend to use the pedal more liberally--Feinberg, Richter, Gavrilov, Nikolayeva, Afannasiev, etc.") at https://www.talkclassical.com/53980-bach-piano-pedal.html (comment #7)